# Список Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

Такая вот трабла. имеется функция. Так вот, функция создает двумерный массив `20х20`, для примера:

```
L=[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
```

но при попытке присвоить любому элементу другое значение я столкнулся с такой проблемой:

```
L[0][0] = 5
```

вывод:

```
L=[[5,0,0,0],[5,0,0,0],[5,0,0,0],[5,0,0,0]]
```

если это никак не пофиксить то подскажите плз, как можно создать нормально работающий двумерный массив кодом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код нужно добавлять текстом, а не картинкой. Кроме того, необходимо давать такие названия, которые кратко описывают проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это классическая проблема неправильного использования ссылок на объекты.

Ты, получается, добавляешь ссылку на один и тот же объект в лист несколько раз, поэтому твой `L[0]` этот тот же объект, что и `L[1]`, `L[2]` и так далее.

Простым фиксом этой проблемы будет создание внутреннего нового листа внутри цикла:

```
STOLBCI = STROKI = 20 

def chernmatrix():
    return [[0 for _ in range(STOLBCI)]
            for _ in range(STROKI)]
```

Заодно и [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) применили.

Другим вариантом решения проблемы будет использование [`copy.copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.copy), поверхстностно копируя существующий лист на каждом этапе цикла:

```
import copy

# ...

stroki = 20
while stroki > 0:
    K.append(copy.copy(L))
    stroki -= 1
```

Comment: второй вариант переделал под себя и все заработало, спасибо.
первый конечно будет получше без лишнего импорта, но пока не поумнею и так сойдет. про генераторы только мельком читал и почему-то первый код у меня не пашет. если не трудно, можете запилить работающую функцию с первым кодом? проще будет понять что делаю не так. но пока и на этом спасибо.

Comment: @СеняСенечкин отлично. Обновил ответ с полной версией функции в первом варианте. Главное, что Вы поняли идею, в чем была проблема, а дальше уже дело техники и опыта. Спасибо.

Comment: У списков есть свой метод `list.copy`.

Comment: @SourSourse спасибо за подсказку, да, появился в 3.3+.